# Helpdesk / Customer Relationship Management (CRM) software

Tags: help-desk, crm

I'm looking for CRM software that meets the following requirements:

- Web-based (ASP.NET compatible)
- Has an instant messenger feel (e.g. a modal or popup)
- Questions can be sent to our Customer Support department, and the client receives a notification when their questions are answered (real-time)
- Questions can be sent outside office hours so that we can reply ASAP.

Basically, we're changing our customer relationship paradigm. We want our customer support to be as friendly and accessible as possible. We want our reps to get to know the needs of our customers, and I figured a great way to be able to do this is a CRM that's *not* based on creating tickets, sending emails, filling out forms, or other similar methods but to actually make it instantly accessible from any page, any time.

I've looked at intercom.io, and it's almost exactly what we need for our startup, but it's too expensive for our current budget.

Comment: If it helps anyone, we're using Zopim currently.

Answer (score 2):

I could recommend you [Voiptime](https://voiptimecloud.com/call-center/blended-call-center-software), this is multichannel  call centre software which offer inbound, outbound and blended software. Their software is designed to assist a call center team in multiple ways. It synchronizes the process of tracking, managing and routing incoming and outgoing telephone calls as well as route calls to the most appropriate agent.
I've been working with them for 2 years, and quite satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to take a look at [ZenDesk](https://www.zendesk.com/).

I believe it has a realtime chat facility, form facility, and supports followups via email.

Compared to intercom.io, it lacks the customer segmentation, data mining and mass mailing facilities.